# How can I read a text file without any newline or tab characters?

Tags: python

I have a rather long sql query that I want to use in Python.

Rather than type the sql query, or paste it, I'd like to read it from a text file.

However, when I do something like

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
```

The resulting string has new line characters.  How can I read in the string without any of the formating characters?

Note: I could just do `s.replace('\n',' ' )` but suppose the file is too large to read and pick out which characters occur.

Comment: SQL won't bother about tabs or newlines; they are used as whitespace separators, just as spaces.

Comment: "suppose the file is too large to read and pick out which characters occur." what kind of [awful SQL query](http://img.thedailywtf.com/images/201110/query.jpg) would that be?

Comment: @Evert how did you get into my office?

Comment: More seriously: if the file is too large to read, replacing newlines or tabs is the last of your worries: how are you going to read the SQL query in the first place?

Comment: @Evert I'm using sqllite3.  You make a good point that new lines and tabs are whitespace separators, I never thought of that.  I just tried to run the query and everything looks fine.  Thanks

Comment: Sounds correct. I haven't tried this with sqlite in a while, but for PostgreSQL, I often copy-paste queries that are formatted across several lines without a problem. PostgreSQL (and SQLite) just look for the closing `;`. With SQLite, I'd probably just use `sqlite database.db < query.sql`.

Comment: Finally, to answer the question in the title: I doubt you can. Just replace them if you feel it helps (e.g., in logging output).